# Apple math library vs others in C

Tags: ios, c, math, gcc, optimization

Recently I wanted know how fast I can compute `tanh(x)` function in C. So I've written the below easy code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
 
int main() {
    clock_t elapsed1 = -clock();
    double x = 3.14;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)  {
        x = tanh(x);
    }
    elapsed1 += clock();
    printf("X = %f\n", x);
    printf("time %lu\n", elapsed1);
    return 0;
}
```

I've run it on my CPU (2.5GHz on single thread) and got time 370 000 using Ubuntu 15.04. My friend has MacOS 10.10.3 (1.4GHz on single thead) and she got 180 000.

I compiled it with: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lm`
and she: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

I don't understand how can a slower CPU calculate a so naive code snippet almost two times faster? And why doesn't Apple need `-lm`? Is it somehow related?

And if Apple has some great math libraries, is it difficult to implement them in basic C compiler/libraries?  Why?

#### Edit:

Precisely: I have newer and more powerful CPU than her, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Also I've run the code on other machines and they were slower as well.

Comment: maybe it depends on the L1 cache size, the pipeline length etc. You should let us know the type of CPU you have in the two machines.

Comment: Does it compute the same value?

Comment: yes, it does. I have Intel Core i7-4710MQ, not sure what CPU she has, but it is core i5

Comment: Intel also computes tan more than twice as fast, but if you print all the digits (`%.20f`) it differs at the end.

Comment: You're using two different hardware and software environments and trying to benchmark them against each other. Probably one of the most challenging tasks in CS. There's just too many variables in this equation.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I did what you proposed and you are right! Only apple has different result than other environments.

Comment: Might also want to try turning optimizations on (ex: -O2).

Comment: 1. Compart non-optimized code is pointless. 2. You should compare the assembly output of those compilers

Answer (score 1):

I might give brief steps of exploration, no magical solution possible here, but:

1. Your code is very compiler-optimizable. Say, with O2 it may be folded to single instruction. That is why if one compiler is built with different specs (say default -Og instead default -O0) or just newer/older then results will dramatically differ. So you need to explicitly specify `-O0` option and be sure that compiler versions are the same
2. Compiler backend might have builtin for tanh function, so please add `-fno-builtin` to options.
3. libc version may differ -- you need to be sure what exactly libc version used here and there.
4. double precision itself may differ, say 80-bit doubles against 64-bit doubles then some performance is traded for accuracy. Try to use float version instead -- float implementations are almost always 32-bit.
5. There might be arch-specific builtin inside libc function. Say ia64 glibc backend offers highly optimized tanh whereas i386 don't